# Not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pip, command-line-arguments

Our professor has given us the assignment of downloading and setting up...
https://github.com/spyoungtech/hikvision-recover
...for a cyber security class

As stated I used pip to install from the command line. I then test to see if it was successful with
pip show hikvision-recover and it is successful.

[image]

Yet, when I try to run the command on a windows shell I get a "Not recognized as an internal or external command." I'm assuming this has to do with the command not being found? But I'm not really sure where to start.

According to documentation I should just be able to

`hikvision-recover <serial number> <Date information>`

and it will return the recovery password.

Update: When I try python -m  I get
[image]

Comment: pip will have installed an executable to run `hikvision-recover` somewhere but since Windows doesn't have a standard path to place executables, it may not be in your %PATH% and so not findable on the command line. I don't know of an easy way to find out where this directory is but you could brute force it with `dir /s hikvision-recover*`. Once you find that path, add it to your user PATH. It may have other useful scripts from other installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable, if it was created, is not in your path. You can try:

`python -m hikvision-recover <serial number> <Date information>`

Comment: Thanks for the idea but when I try it (see update) it says "no module" by that name. I know the site package is there. I can navigate to it.

Comment: Sounds like the version python used for pip is not the same as for python. You can try calling python by path or you may have aliases for `python3`, `python3.9`, or `python39`. To work around this, you can reinstall with `python -m pip install hikvision-recover`

Comment: Thank you! Trying that it says it is a package and cannot be executed directly. I'm assuming I just need to utilize a script of some kind? Sorry, new to Python. Thanks for at least pointing me in the correct direction.

Comment: Ah, that's a Python 3 thing. Seems they haven't updated it to work with python3 in that way. You can work around this with `python c:\users\<username>\appdata\roaming\python\python3.9\site-packages/hikvision_recover/__init__.py`. That said, this is a workaround, so if you plan on doing more with Python, I would suggest getting your paths sorted.

Comment: It's also possible you can find a script in `c:\users\<username>\appdata\roaming\python\python3.9\Scripts`, but I'm not sure if it installs one or not.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it looks like another user installed Python to a directory, then I installed it to my user account because I did not have admin rights on the PC at that time. Now the paths are messed up. I tried this on my personal PC and it worked. Which is all I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the pip you used to install hikvision-recover is not the same version of python you are using. When installing a module, it is always a good practice to do the following on your command prompt:

```
where python
```

It will show you which python executable the prompt will use where invoke python.

Double check pip is the same version as python:

```
where pip
```

If the version are not the same, you need to modify your environment variable. Go Window menu - Edit the system environment variable - Environment variables - Path (User variable) and modify the order should you have more than one python version on the list.